# How to use default value of a columns in same query on a same table?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a table in MySQL database. In that table, I have two columns which has default integer value assigned. Like 80 and 90. Now, my problem is that when I try to insert a record first time in that table, I want to use those columns(which has default values) in a same insert query. I don't know how to do that. I know that we can achieve that using subquery but I want to know is there a simple way? I even don't know whether it is possible or not? Please guide me soon. Thank you.

Comment: What exaclty do you want to do? An insert query setting the two columns? Something like this: INSERT INTO table (column1,column2) VALUES (80,90);?

Comment: Do you want to do an insert and use the default values of columns?

Comment: Just dont mention the columns in the insert statement... MySQL will figure out you want to use the default values for those fields

Comment: if you want to use default values, don't mention them in the insert coomand, for example INSERT into table (col3, col4) values (...), so col1 and col2 have the default values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I want to use those values in a same query and found the answer. I just directly use the column name in a query where we mention values...like.....

"INSERT INTO sohan_password_management(id, name, user_password, register_date, prompt_date, deadline) VALUES('$id', '$name', '$user_hash', NOW(), NOW() + INTERVAL default_prompt_date DAY, NOW() + INTERVAL default_deadline DAY)"

....BTW Thank you everyone for taking time out to share your answers with me. Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use default values, don't mention the columns in the insert command.

For example `INSERT into table A (col3, col4) values (...)`, so `col1` and `col2` have the default values